# unwanted shaking with background change. Picture and color chance

Tags: html, css

First of all, I'm a beginner in programming.

I will appreciate some help from someone. I have a background I want to change with keyframes pictures and color. It works, but I have some problems with some unwanted shaking when the picture change. I don´t use javascript for this one.

#### My css

```
section#home{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
        animation: bgswap 50s;
      -webkit-animation: bgswap 50s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite; 

  
.BackColorChange {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
                animation: colorchange 25s;
              -webkit-animation: colorchange 25s;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
                -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
                -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
                -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
                animation-timing-function: linear;
        }
        @keyframes colorchange
        {
            0%   {background: rgba(255,252,252,.75);}
            25%  {background: rgba(224,214,204,.5);}
            50%  {background: rgba(209,195,182,0);}
            75%  {background: rgba(224,214,204,.5);}
            100% {background: rgba(255,252,252,.75);}
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes colorchange
        {
            0%   {background: rgba(255,252,252,.75);}
            25%  {background: rgba(224,214,204,.5);}
            50%  {background: rgba(209,195,182,0);}
            75%  {background: rgba(224,214,204,.5);}
            100% {background: rgba(255,252,252,.75);}
        }
        @keyframes bgswap {
            0%   {background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/1/b/431542.jpg");}
            20%  {background-image: url("https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-57593.jpg");}
            40%  {background-image: url("https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-57593.jpg");}
            60%  {background-image: url("https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-57593.jpg");}
            80%  {background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/1/b/431542.jpg");}
            100% {background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/1/b/431542.jpg");}
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes bgswap {
            0%   {background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/1/b/431542.jpg");}
            20%  {background-image: url("https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-57593.jpg");}
            40%  {background-image: url("https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-57593.jpg");}
            60%  {background-image: url("https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-57593.jpg");}
            80%  {background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/1/b/431542.jpg");}
            100% {background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/1/b/431542.jpg");}
        }
```

Comment: this is because the image are not loaded and you need to wait for them ... search of pre-load techniques ... by the way you are not calling the image animation here ?

Comment: Okay, thanks. Where do I call the image animation and is it still in css.

Comment: You are using the `background` shorthand property in the animation, so it resets properties such as `background-size` to their defaults.

Comment: I did find this one. 

This on is for pre-load. 
body::after{
    position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1;
    content:url(img01.png) url(img02.png) url(img03.png) url(img04.png);
}

Can I use that? 

So the background size. Do I need to change from cover to absolute or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @JesperLeoMoberg In the colorchange animation, you use the property `background`, which is a shorthand that not only sets the background color, but also all other background properties, In other words once the animation starts, it changes the `background-size` from `cover` to `auto`. What you should to to avoid that is use only `background-color` in the animation rather than `background`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I will try something until it works. Help a lot with my understanding.